# Spring Data JPA - Select row for update

Tags: spring, db2, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement to read the first enabled account from DB2 database table and immediately update the column to disable it. While server 1 is reading and updating the column, no other server should be able to read the same row since I want one account to be used by only one server at a time.

This is what I have so far..

Account.java

```
   Account{
       private Long id;
       private Character enabled;
       .............
   }
```

AccountRepository.java

```
   public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long>{
      Account findFirstByEnabled(new Character('Y'));    
  }
```

AccountServiceImpl.java

```
 @Service
 public class AccountServiceImpl {

      @Autowrired 
      private AccountRepository accntRepository;

      @Transactional
      public Account findFirstAvaialbleAccount(){

          Account account = accntRepository.findFirstByEnabled(new Character('Y'));

          if(account != null)
          {
            account.setEnabled(new Character('N')); //put debug point here
             account.save(proxyAccount);
          }

      return account; 
     }
 }
```

But this isn't working.. I've put a debug pointer in the findFirstAvaialbleAccount() method. What I was expecting is, if the debug pointer reaches that line and waiting for me to resume execution, if I run select query directly on the database, the sql shouldn't execute. It should only execute after I resume the execution on the server so that transaction is completed. But instead, running the select query directly on the database gave me the complete result set immediately. What am I missing here? I'm using DB2 if it matters.

Comment: Why do you think putting a breakpoint on a Java program should prevent another program from executing a query? Would IBM be able to sell DB2 to anyone if only one transaction reading from a table blocked all the other transactions?

Comment: Pessimistic logging is done at Database level.. with the transaction pending in server, DB2 shouldn't allow for any other client to read the same row

Comment: Why? Why do you assume that pessimistic locking is used when you haven't used any lock? Why would it prevent a transaction from **reading** a row that another transaction **reads**.

Comment: yeah that was my mistake.. I forgot to put "for update" in the query I was running directly against DB.. the one I was running from sever had it, but not the one in terminal window..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question... I had incorrect Select SQL running against the database. If I run the select sql with "select.. for update", then the execution waits until I hit resume on the server and transaction is complete.

SQL 1 - this executes immediately even though the transaction from server isn't complete.

select * from MYTABLE where ENABLED = 'Y';

SQL 2-  this waits until the transaction from server is complete (it will probably timeout if I don't hit resume quick enough)

select * from MYTABLE where ENABLED = 'Y' 
fetch first 1 rows only with rs use and keep update locks;